# Remapping stack succeeds, but later SEGV is raised

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64, mmap

I ran a simple program written in assembly that under `strace` that simply executes `SYS_exit`.

```
_start:
    mov rax, 0x3C
    mov rdi, 0x0
    syscall
```

And noticed that there were nothing like `mmap` memory for the stack:

```
alrorp@dmspc:~$ strace ./bin 
execve("./bin", ["./bin"], 0x7ffd591eda80 /* 65 vars */) = 0
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

So I tried to do `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` to the stack page-aligned address as follows:

```
int main(void){
    int a = 1;
    void *ptr = &a;
    void *page_aligned_ptr = (void *)((intptr_t) ptr & -4096);
    mmap(page_aligned_ptr, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FIXED | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
}
```

The thing is it segfaults after the call to `mmap` succeeds (i.e. it returns the requested address instead of `MAP_FAILED`).

```
mmap(0x7ffdf50db000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffdf50db000
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=NULL} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault
```

Can you give any hint about this behavior? Core dump seems to be (almost) useless in that case with stack corrupted.

Does something like create a custom mapping for stack even make sense?

Comment: Who knows what the startup code that calls your `main()` had on its version of the stack that wasn't there after you memory mapped the stack elsewhere.  It seems like a pretty bad idea.  It could be worse because you returned rather than calling `exit()`.  With a call to `exit()`, you might get away with it, but …

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if you `mmap` space onto the address range used by the stack, then won't you thereby effectively clobber the stack?  A segfault on (attempted) return from the function seems a natural result.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yeah, seems really obvious to me, too.  Didn't take long to think of + write my answer.  I thought about closing or downvoting as too obvious, but apparently it wasn't obvious to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing the stack page containing your return address with a new anonymous page of zero bytes obvious leads to a segfault as soon as `main` returns, and pops `0` into RIP.

Note the `si_addr=NULL`, IIRC that's the code address where the fault happened.  So RIP=0 after running a `ret` with RSP pointing at a `0`.  (**The `ret` itself won't fault, but code-fetch from address `0` will.**)

Or actually the segfault will be inside the libc wrapper for `mmap`, which itself has to `ret`.

**Use a debugger to single-step the asm the C compiler created for you.**

Comment: Yes, it received segv in `mmap` while trying to return. The `strace` output was misleading.

Comment: Anyway, it is not specified in the [ABI](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) how the memory for stack is mapped. All what was mentioned was the `exec` should take care of it.

Comment: @St.Antario: misleading how?  `ret` succeeds (setting RIP=0), then code-fetch from address 0 segfaults.  Use GDB if `strace` doesn't make it obvious.  Plus, it doesn't matter *how* the stack got mapped, just that a local variable is typically in the same page as your return address.